# Java generics and casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java generics, if you type

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l2 = l; //no casting works here
```

It won’t compile, reporting inconvertible types `List<Object> to List<String>`. However:

```
List<? extends Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l2 = ( List<String> ) l;
List<String> l3 = ( List<String> ) l;
```

Does work. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

That's because `List<? extends Object>` *might* actually refer to a `List<String>` and thus the compiler has to trust the developer.

In the first case the compiler *knows* that the cast will mess with the assumptions other code will have (i.e. that you can put every kind of object into `l` and that `l2` will only contain strings) and thus is able to refuse the cast.

The same (or something similar) happens with plain objects:

```
Integer i = new Integer(1);
String s = (String)i;
```

The above will fail because the compiler knows that an `Integer` object can't possibly be cast to `String`.

However, the following at least compiles since the compiler doesn't know the actual type of `i` (think of `i` coming from elsewhere in your code) and thus the compiler has to trust you know what you're doing.

```
Object i = new Integer(1);
String s = (String)i;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l2 = l; //no casting works here
```

It doesn't work because you are assigning `List<Object>` to `List<String>`
however these are incompatible types;

```
List<? extends Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l2 = ( List<String> ) l;
List<String> l3 = ( List<String> ) l;
```

This works because, at compile time it checks that `List<? extends Object>` can be casted to `List<String>`

When we don't use `extends` keyword the types are expected to be exact.